# Flag was declined for exact duplicate, but clearly it is an exact duplicate

Tags: discussion, support, flags, duplicate-questions, declined-flags

So I flagged the question *[Conditional CSS for Internet Explorer 10 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550890)* as a dupe of the question *[How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-ie10-for-certain-situations-like-ie-specific-css-or-ie-spec/13954700#13954700)*

In my flagging history it says the following:

> exact duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311 – Mar 21 at 15:14   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Only I can't understand why it was declined, because they got the ***exact same answer!***.

Answer from the duplicate:

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 10) {
    $(".jMenu li ul").css("margin", "1px");
}
```

Answer from the original:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 10) {
    $("html").addClass("ie10");
}
```

If you take out `parseInt` and an `=` then you get the exact same thing...

The jQuery, JavaScript and HTML tags are already full of crap, it's so easy to see this is a duplicate. Can it please be marked as such?

Comment: We can't see your flag summery. Only you and moderators can.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha oh, that's interesting, I didn't know that even if I put a direct link to my history people could not see it. Thanks for the heads up. Was worth asking this question just to learn that.

Comment: I've had this happen to me too.  Except another moderator went and closed it as the very question I suggested :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's a duplicate, so I've gone ahead and marked it as such.

Perhaps the moderator who processed your flag wasn't sure if they were really exact duplicates and didn't feel like taking a closer look. Or maybe because the question hadn't been marked as a dupe after nearly a week since it was posted and since you flagged it, and the moderator took that to mean "no, it's not really a dupe after all".

Comment: I'm not sure how the flag dialog works, but a moderator shouldn't decline a flag because they're feeling lazy.. Should they?

Comment: I would imagine this might be a case of one flag on the question not applying (e.g., spam or offensive) and all the flags being dismissed as a result.

Comment: @Seth: That was slightly tongue-in-cheek, but there are so many flags that certain categories that get flagged in bulk, such as close flags, tend to get less attention than others like vandalism, bad behavior, or other special flags. In any case, we do either slip up or have differing opinions on flags (or both).

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: That is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock'saUnicorn I've seen you a lot in the html/javascript tags and I appreciate all you do to clean them up. As I'm sure your aware, those tags really are a mess.

Comment: @ryan: Thanks, I do what I can :)

Answer (score 3):

Most moderators are only human, and as such are not going to be experts in every area. When you pick "flag to close" with one of the standard options (such as dup, not a real question, too localized, etc etc) make sure it's *obvious* to someone who doesn't know that language that it really should be closed that way.

You always have the option of "other" and you can write a summary there. If you know it's a dup, but there's a chance it wouldn't be obvious to someone else, then select other, add the link for the dup and add in all the comments you can to prove your point. You'll have a much better shot of the mod agreeing with you. (assuming you were right of course.)